# Startup.cs file in ASP.NET MVC is not shown

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

[image]Hey I updated the VS2022 to last version and when I created a new MVC project I couldn't find startup file in soulation only the program.cs found? Is it normal? and how to add this code in program

```
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Comment: To register services (as `AddDbContext()` does), you need a place in your project where services are registered. This is typically done in Startup.cs. Based on the provided information it's impossible to understand how your project looks like so it's impossible to answer this question. The easiest possibility would be, that you selected a wrong project type and created a console app. I'd simply try it again with a new project.

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping me.
i edited the question with an img. 
i created asp.net mvc project and that's what i get

Comment: Can you share your program.cs code?

Comment: You're using a preview version of visual studio. You'll have to read the blog posts and analyze what's inside your Program.cs to understand if this is a bug or expected behavior.  Given your question, I'd strongly recommend to use the latest stable version instead.

Comment: the problem was in .Net6 (preview) 
when i created new project with .Net5 it works fine

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In .Net 6.0 the `program.cs` and `startup.cs` have been unified. You can check the documentation in [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 5.0 to 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

It is a similar process to insert your context just as you have done in startup.cs.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is bit late but with the unified model, the dependency injection could be done at program.cs itself as shown below.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<StoresContext>(options => 
   options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey I know you said that you just used .NET 5.0 but for anyone who is using .NET 6.0 to run

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

All you need to do is add the following variable

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```

And when you call the function

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

And you should have no problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, You have opened an empty new project. If you create new emot project, you must add startup.cs file

Answer (score 0):

For me I added the services by using this code in Program.cs file :

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHISInterface<Users> , UsersRepositiry>();
```